# How to catch a response in a "POST" request?

Tags: php, jquery, json, post, http-post

I have an html/jQuery webPage and a PHP server. From the webPage i am making a "post" request to my server like this :

```
var data = '{"deviceUUID":"' + userId + '"}'
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "http://192.138.2.113/Server_CityInfo/whereSubscribed.php",
                     data: data 
                     })
```

As you can see i only send an *id* , in json format. The request arrives at the server and after some "cooking" i make an echo from the server back to the webPage :

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

Sorry if my question sound stupid , but how do i "catch" this echo to my webPage with jquery?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: @Quentin: That link would be more helpful if it pointed to the actual documentation that describes how to do this.  Either you don't know where it is, or your comment is a thinly-veiled RTFM.

Comment: The thing is the OP apparently read the FM , on the good page, but didn't understand it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP server is on a separate origin (different ip, domain, subdomain, or protocol) than the web page. Because of this, your request is being caught by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

There are three common ways to fix this:

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), but that would mean having to use GET rather than POST, and the server will have to return data in the JSONP format.

You can use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but the PHP Server would have to implement cors headers and you would have to implement a patch to jQuery (or send the request manually) to support IE8 and IE9. IE7 does not support CORS at all.

The third option is to use a proxy either on your webserver, or on a third party server that properly implements CORS or JSONP. A common third party service that helps with this is [YQL](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/&ei=Fb2bUeOPOI_A9gTHjoDgBg&usg=AFQjCNFovrKTbOzxH_-EkjRDmx1T9v6odw&sig2=iHV3UDHEjHo3ndUvbR3z5A&bvm=bv.46865395,d.eWU), and there's a very well done example **[here](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/)**.

Comment: I didnt see anywhere the option to put my front-end(html-jquery) in the same folder with my back-end(php server). That should work right? Right now i have both of them in the same local machine , but inside different "projects" on eclipse. That means different subdomains. But there is no particular reason that they are in different folders. Is just the frond-end and the back-end of a webservice. I ll try put them together and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

In success handler like this -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.138.2.113/Server_CityInfo/whereSubscribed.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data); // here you got `$result` in data
    }
});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Wouldn't you need `dataType: 'json'` as well?

Comment: Yes, but not if you are going to use `$.parseJSON()` instead

Comment: Code doesnt give error , but alerts nothing. Like the function is not called.

Comment: Any error on your browser console ?

Comment: That means you are getting an error, add an error callback.

Comment: How does this mean that i am getting an error , and how do i add an error callback? :D

Comment: what is the URL of the page you're doing this ajax query from ?

Comment: Well, if the success callback isn't firing, the only alternative is the error callback. Here's a page with examples of how to include the error callback: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/ (*which just so happens to be a page one click away from the one Quinten linked.*)

Comment: Yeap i am getting an error :D But i dont see any way here , how to see whats really wrong..

Comment: @Bartdude , why are u asking about the URL ?

Comment: cause cross-domain ajax request can be a pain in the ass

Comment: no no everything is local on my server. Really? So i might develop smth that works locally and then have problems when it goes in an external server?

Comment: @KevinB its really strange , cause wherever i add the error callback it is triggered and shows me an error! Even in those http post requests that they work. I can see that they are working , as i am getting the json files to the server. Why are they triggered? Is really confusing to understand whats wrong , even when the things that work , show that they are wrong..

Comment: `error: function(xhr, status, message) { alert("Status: " + status + "\nMessage: " + message); }`

Comment: Status: error , Message:

Comment: Thats exactly what i am getting. Empty message body.

Comment: Open your browser's console, you most likely are getting "Access Denied" it's F12 in IE and Ctrl+shift+j in Chrome. This is the first thing you should do any time you are having a javascript problem.

Comment: actually i am getting nothing in the console. Only a warning : Timestamp: 5/21/2013 8:01:05 PM
Warning: Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: http://localhost/ClientSide/test_jquery.html
Line: 0

Comment: @user2394470 Next step is to build a basic html form that posts to that url with the same parameters that your current request is sending to see what it is returning. *(or you can open your console's network tab and inspect the request)*

Comment: Hmm i dont really understand u. My example is pretty basic already. And how can i see what is returning i dont undertand? What is this console u r refering to ?

Comment: What browser are you using? each has it's own console with differing capabilities

Comment: i am using firefox. It has errors, warnings, messages tabs

Comment: Download the firebug extension, or use google chrome. Firefox's console doesn't come with a network tab.

Comment: yes it shows me in the post the json i am sending , but nothing in the response. So that means there is a problem from the server? It doesnt respond correctly?

Comment: So, the response body/preview areas are blank? that would indicate a server error, but you should have also gotten a 500 status in the error callback, or even parseerror in the message. weird.

Comment: on chrome i get the name of the php script that the request is going , the method is POST , the status is (cancelled) and the type is pending , if it helps. And also : XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.4.113/Server_CityInfo/whereSubscribed.php. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: There's the problem. You're making a cross-origin POST request, that's not going to work unless you implement CORS on the cross-origin server, which isn't completely supported in IE<10 (partially supported in IE8+, not supported at all in <IE8. IE8-IE9 require a patch to jQuery)

Comment: Hmm looks like you understand whats the problem which is really great :D . However i understood nothing of what you said haha :) . Could you explain me in simpler words and guide me the right direction here?

Comment: Basically, you are making a POST request to a domain that is not the same domain as the current page. This is a security risk and is not allowed unless the server you are requesting from supports CORS. Here is a link that explains what CORS is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score -2):

You need to use a callback method which will treat the response when it comes back (as it is asynchrone)...

Comment: can I ask why the downvote ? Maybe the answer is not detailed much, but the question doesn't show much research effort neither, and I don't think my answer is that wrong...

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think it's because you didn't say what the name of the callback method was called.

Comment: My first reaction was "well, how would I do *that?*"

Comment: i didnt downvote either , but what do u mean the question doesnt show much research effort? I suppose there is only 1 way to do what i am asking and thats what i am asking. If i had the answer there would be no question.What kind of research could i do? I didnt find the answer or google so i ask here..

Comment: @user2394470 : well, jquery doc (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is pretty clear about the solution, and the "callback" keyword in my answer even point you to what you need to look in it. Looking at the docs seems to me to be the least research effort one can do before posting a question, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: oh i read that. Didnt make any sense to me to tell u the truth.

Comment: Well... the doc is rather clear and has quite some good examples on it. Anyway I was just trying to get an explanation on the downvotes. Next time I'll just shut up and wait for others to bother answering with plenty of (apparently useless) details...

Comment: I fully understand you man. My question on the first 2 mins had 3 downvotes. Why? Is a programming question , is clear , for sure someone will have the same question so its more or less helpful for others. But still lets burn it cause for some people the answer is "too obvious".

Comment: Honestly, if I were you I would invest some time in trying to understand jQuery doc. most of the time it really is well done and documented...